# 2nd line: timestamp of messages?

Tags: sms, voip

I'm using 2nd line as my primary phone number, and I see that messages are sometimes "bunched" together making it impossible to tell even what hour a message was sent.

Is there any means to get the timestamp of (all) 2nd line messages?

Are there any known bugs associated with timestamps of 2nd line messages?

Comment: By "2nd line" did you mean this [2ndLine](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.enflick.android.tn2ndLine) (no space)?